# Update using XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update a table using an xml.

```
UPDATE dbo.M_Picture
SET Sequence = T.c.query('Sequence')
FROM dbo.M_Picture pic
INNER JOIN @xml.nodes('/pictures/picture') T(c)
ON pic.PictureId = T.c.query('pictureId') --I guess issue is in this line
```

The XML I am using is

```
<pictures>
  <picture>
    <pictureId>30</pictureId>
    <Sequence>4</Sequence>
  </picture>
  <picture>
    <pictureId>31</pictureId>
    <Sequence>4</Sequence>
  </picture>
</pictures>
```

The error message I am getting is

> Operand type clash: xml is incompatible with int

And it makes sense because in

```
pic.PictureId=T.c.query('pictureId')
```

`pictureId` is `int`

How to sort this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE dbo.M_Picture
SET Sequence = T.c.query('Sequence')  -- this here *also* assign an XML fragment to "Sequence"
FROM dbo.M_Picture pic
INNER JOIN @xml.nodes('/pictures/picture') T(c)
ON pic.PictureId = T.c.value('(pictureId)[1]', 'int')
```

Use the `.value()` method on the XML - that returns a scalar type (like `int`)

Also: I'm not sure if you really want to assign the XML fragment `<Sequence>4</Sequence>` to your column `Sequence` - or whether you want to use the `.value()` method there, too!